# How to bulk replace A.b to A('b') in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to bulk replace `A.b` to `A('b')` in Sublime text editor , but I don't know how to write the regex expression.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Search for `\bA\.b\b` and then replace with `A('b')`.

Comment: remove the regex search and directly search for A.b

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that b is a variable

Answer (score 1):

Use find and replace. 
Cmd+f or cmd+shift+f 
ctrl+f /crtr+shift+f (windows)